# Deployment to Websphere (WAS) - application has status 'unknown' after start

Tags: deployment, websphere

I am currently trying to get an application running on a Websphere Application Server [1] (commonly shortened to 'WAS') Docker image [2].

I can connect to the websphere online console (wsadmin) and use it to create a new Enterprise application based on a .war file. I created an application, decided not to run it in distributed mode, but kept the other settings to their default values. The application has been created successfully, I can see it under Applications > Websphere Enterprise Applications.

-But it has the application status 'unknown', which does not change if I start or stop it (neither starting nor stopping generates an error message in the online console).

So without any feedback and as a complete newby to WAS, I have no idea how to further deploy this application.

**How can I get an application status, start the application or get at least an error message to make some progress?**

---

EDIT 1

The log directory /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/server1 contains (_only) the following log files:

- logdata

  - (multiple logs in the form) {id like 1628494344657_368}_server1
- tracedata

  - 1628494344624_368-server1.lock
- List item
- (multiple logs in the form) TextLog_{YY}.{MM}.{DD}_{hh}.{mm}.{ss}_server1.log
- hpelRepository.owner
- logViewer.pos
- native_stderr.log
- native_stdout.log
- server1.pid
- startServer.log
- (multiple logs in the form) verbosegc.{index starting at 001}.log

Since I haven't found something like systemErr/Out.log, I have looked into most of the files. I didn't find an obvious error message at the end of these files (- the ones dated for today seemed to contain more useful information, like documents being created during deployment of my example application, I can add them if someone needs them to help me).

---

[1] Server Version: 9.0.5 
[2] Docker image used: ibmcom/websphere-traditional@sha256:334dede7396a7ff372b048a974f676969e0d847ceba30b3e81b255a86bc42500

Comment: You want to look at the server logs for an error.  For typical docker image, the log directory is /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/server1/.  Look at SystemErr/Out.log as a starting point.  You can update your post with any errors/exceptions you find.  You may also find FFDCs (another type of error log WAS uses) in /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/ffdc/.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. I also don't seem to have a SystemErr directory inside the ....../logs/server1 directory, therefor I cannot look into SystemErr/Out.log. I have looked into native_stderr.log and some other files, but haven't found anything directly hinting at my problem. I updated the question and added the directory structure of the server1-directory

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot that the dockerized version has HPEL enabled (see https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/9.0.5?topic=applications-high-performance-extensible-logging-hpel) which uses different log files.  Look at the TextLog*.log files for errors/exceptions.  Also, did you find any FFDCs as I described above?

Comment: Yeah, the ffdc directory exists. Hadn't looked into it until now, but it contains many logs and it looks like there are some stack traces, that seems to be helpful. With a bit of luck, I'll find the reason for it here